# How to find Active Directory domains on network

Tags: active-directory

Any advice on the best way to discover AD domains on a network would be helpful.

Scenario: 10 AD domains located all over the network. No trusts between the domains. No common DNS server. Admin has access to 1 domain and is unaware of other 9. Looking for ways to discover these other domains. (e.g. looking for 389 traffic, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know all IP range, so please scan all of them.

Generally speaking in the open port you will have the DNS for all the DC.

You can issue an **nbtstat** after to find the domain from computer that are possible DC from what you discovered;

> nbtstat -A IP_ADDRESS

It would issue an answer like that;

[image]

In that picture, (sorry it's in French), my computer is in a workgroup mode and I issued the command to a DC, which you can see the command found the domain name in the second row, type called Groupe.

I dont think nbtstat command are routable on a VPN, so I would recommand to issue it locally from the subnet if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Run a network scan for TCP port 88 or TCP port 389. These systems will be Domain Controllers.

Comment: add 636 for LDAP with SSL.